# get selector of specific div in jsplumb

Tags: javascript, jsplumb

I created a div and I want to make it draggable using:

```
mydiv_selector = jsplumb.getSelector('.classname');
JSPLUMB_INSTANCE.draggable(mydiv);
```

how do I get the "selector" of a specific div? (instead of getting the selector of all divs in that classname) jsplumb.getSelector() seems to take a classname, but I have many elements in that class. Can I get the specific div by ID or something else?

Comment: I want to make that div a source/target on creation but if I use mydiv = jsplumb.getSelector('.classname'); I fetch all the divs in that class and it adds endpoints to them. If there is a way to select only one div and make it a source/target it would work nicely

Comment: Did you try giving the div an ID? You seem to answer your own question.

Comment: I did give it an id. How do I pass that to the getSelector function?
jsplumb.getSelector(my_div_id) doesn't work @isherwood

Comment: Seems like it would be `jsplumb.getSelector('#your_div_id')`, no?

Comment: Doesn't seem like that method takes an argument. http://jsplumb.org/apidocs/files/jquery-jsPlumb-1-3-16-all-js.html#getSelector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return the selectors of a class this works:

```
mydiv_class_selectors = jsplumb.getSelector('.classname');
```

but if I want the selector of a specific div I can get it by id using:

```
mydiv_selector = jsplumb.getSelector('#divid');
```